# Como ler as especificações de um Web Service REST

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, wsdl

Oi,

Eu preciso criar um projeto com consiste de consumir um web service REST,
aonde consumindo esse web service eu preciso gerar um XML com as informações/especificações dele,
quais são os seus métodos, tipos de retorno do método, parâmetros dos métodos e etc ...

Como fazer isso?

Comment: O que não tem solução, solucionado está! Se não existe especificação ou documentação do serviço (consumível por máquina), parece que não tem jeito. Ou isso, ou não entendi a pergunta. Aliás, dê uma olhada na [help] do site, e tente [edit] a pergunta para se encaixar melhor no nosso formato. Fazendo isso, a pergunta vai para uma fila de análise, e usuários experientes irão considerar sua reabertura.

Comment: Creio que deva ser reaberta, você não está querendo dizer sobre WADL's ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049117/enhancing-wadl-with-json-and-xml